# What's the best way to work with a relational firestore model?

Tags: reactjs, redux, google-cloud-firestore, nosql, react-redux-firebase

I followed this video on the best practices for creating flat databases with firestore: [Converting SQL structures to Firebase structures](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ran_Ylug7AE)

I came up with something that looks like this:

```js
const firestore = {
    events: {
        eventID: { // Doc
            description: "Event Description", // Field
            title: "Event Title", // Field
        }
    },

    eventComments: { // Collection
        eventID: { // Doc
            comments: { // Field
                commentID1: true, // Value
                commentID2: true, // Value
                commentID3: true, // Value
            }
        }
    },

    comments: { // Collection
        commentID1: { // Doc
            createdAt: "Timestamp", // Field
            createdBy: "uid", // Field
            content: "Comment Body" // Field
        },
        commentID2: {...},
        commentID3: {...},
    },
};
```

## I'm not sure what the best way to get the related data is however

I'm using **react** and [react-redux-firestore](https://react-redux-firebase.com/docs/firestore) to access the data. My current setup for the app looks like this

```
<EventsDetailPage>
    <Comments>
        <Comment />
        <Comment />
        <Comment />
    </Comments>
</EventsDetailPage>
```

[image]

I've come up with two potential methods...

### Method 1

I have `useFirestoreConnect` in each component. The top level gets the `event` and passes the `eventID` to the comments component, the comments component uses the `eventID` to get the `eventComments` list which passes the individual `commentID` for each comment to the comment component, then finally the individual comment component uses the `commentID` to get the relevant comment data.

**My issue with this: Wouldn't this mean that there is a listener for the event, comment list, and every individual comment? Is that frowned upon?**

EX: This would be in the event, the comments, and comment component but each with respective values

```js
useFirestoreConnect(() => [
        {collection: 'events', doc: eventID},
]);

const event = useSelector(({firestore: {data}}) => data.events && data.events[eventID]);
```

### Method 2

Let's say I have a list of events, I can do a query to get the lists

```js
useFirestoreConnect(() => [{
        collection: 'events',
        orderBy: ["createdAt", "desc"],
        limitTo: 10
    }]);

    const events = useSelector(({ firestore: { ordered } }) => ordered.events);
```

This is great because I believe it's one listener but if any of the data is changed in any of the events the listener will still respond to the changes.

**My issue with this: I don't know how to do a where clause that would return all events for a given list of IDs.**

So like say if I wanted to get a list of events with `where: ['id', '==', ['eventID1', 'eventID2', 'eventID3']]`

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve up to 10 items by their ID, you can [use an `in` query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_and_array-contains-any):

```
.where('id', 'in', ['eventID1', 'eventID2', 'eventID3'])
```

If you have more than 10 IDs, you'll have to run multiple of these queries.

Comment: ah okay, but what about getting the comment data to use as another query. How would that work with the redux setup?

Comment: @CTOverton Whenever possible, you should let the parent component of a list handle bundled queries. An "event list" component would make the Firebase query and create "event details" components for each event passing in the relevant data. Each "event details" component contains an "event comments" component that does the same using the relevant event ID. The component fetches the comment data and adds "comment" components to itself for each comment. The comment component can either be standalone in it's own class or just a `div` on the "event comments" component.

Comment: The most important thing is to unsubscribe the listeners once you've removed their components. If you don't, Firebase could be pushing out data to your client that is not used for anything.

Comment: @samthecodingman your first comment is very much like what I have. A component for each piece that passes along the id's so each component can make a call with a listener to get the data. I think with react-redux-firestore it should automatically unsubscribe the listeners. My biggest thing is, does it make sense to have a listener for every single comment? I don't know how else you would do that. At least with the event list it's one listener but I don't know how to query for id's of comments